# How do I modify this powershell script so it creates a log of the date time and names of all files that were deleted or previously deleted?

Tags: powershell

I wanted to make a PowerShell script that deleted any type of file in a certain folder when they were 7 days old. The problem I am having is creating a log file with the date, time, and names of all the files that were deleted or were previously deleted when the script ran.

I am wondering if there is a way of modifying the answer found on this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326171/powershell-script-to-delete-sub-folders-and-files-if-creation-date-is-7-days-bu?lq=1

I would like it so that instead of sending an email with the report it will create one log file of all the files deleted with the names, time, and dates in the folder that I am storing the script (Please note I'd like it to append the log file each time not overwrite it). I am sorry because I do not know how to code so I have been stuck trying to do this myself for a long time now and I have been asking questions and such but still can't seem to get it to work. So yea if anyone can modify that script it would be very appreciated! Thank you!

Here is what I did with the script (if it helps) , but it doesn't work (Again I do not know how to code):

```
$report_items = @()
# set folder path
$dump_path = "C:FileDeleter\AutoDeleteFilesInThisFolder"
# set min age of files
$max_days = "-7"
# get the current date
$curr_date = Get-Date
# determine how far back we go based on current date
$del_date = $curr_date.AddDays($max_days)
# get the sub directories
$sub_dirs = Get-ChildItem $dump_path | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer }
$sub_dirs | % {
    if (Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt     $del_date } ) {
        $report_items += New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
            Time = Get-Date -f "hh:mm:ss"
            Message = "Skipping " + $_.FullName + " because it contains items newer     than " + $del_date
        }
    }
    else {
        Remove-Item $_.FullName -Recurse
        $report_items += New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
            Time = Get-Date -f "hh:mm:ss"
            Message = "Deleting " + $_.FullName + " because it contains no items newer     than " + $del_date
        }
    }
}
$report_items | out-file "C:\FileDeleter\PruningReport.txt"
```

Comment: You should tell us what behaviour you're seeing and how that differs from what you're expecting.  I can't see how `$report_items` gets set and I also note that your `out-file` call will overwrite the file every time - you might want to try `-Append`

Comment: It is not necessary to put `[UNSOLVED]` or `[SOLVED]` in your titles. If it's been solved, you should have accepted the answer that provided the solution, and the fact you have not done so indicates it's unsolved. Please don't clutter your question title with the extra noise that isn't needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\FileDeleter\AutoDeleteFilesInThisFolder" -Filter *.torrent -Recurse | Where { $_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7) } | %{Remove-Item -Force; if ($?) {"$(Get-Date -Format 'MM-dd-yy HH:mm:ss.ff')  $_.Name" | Add-Content 'C:\FileDeleter\PruningReport.txt'}}
```

(The reason for the `if ($?)` block is to only write a log entry if the file deletion was successful - you don't want to assume that it was.)

Comment: Actually, this makes it a lot *more* confusing, because I'd need to read the original script and figure out what it's doing, then read your script and try to find what changes you made, and figure out what you're trying to accomplish with those changes. None of that is very clear. Instead, can you tell me what the error was?

Comment: I'm not looking to answer questions to this answer... I need help with answering the quesion I have for the other answer... Thanks. Please read it below!

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say. In any case, what I posted solves your original question according to my testing. If you have a new question, you should accept the answer to this question (as originally asked) and post a new question. You should NOT edit the question to ask something different after people have already responded to the question you originally asked. Edits should be for clarity and to add relevant information, not to say "never mind what I asked and the answers I received, I've decided to ask something different instead."

Comment: It actually doesn't let me upvote comments or accept answers... Idk... But uhh your answer wasn't exactly it either... Here is the full correct answer: `Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\FileDeleter\AutoDeleteFilesInThisFolder" -Recurse | Where { $_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7) } | Tee-Object -FilePath "C:\FileDeleter\ARGH - ME BOOTY (File Deletion Log).txt" -Append | Remove-Item -Force` Now like I said I would upvote yours but I can't...

Comment: Okay, you do need at least 50 rep to upvote/downvote. But you don't need any rep to accept answers (in fact, you gain +2 rep for each accept). You accept answers by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer.

Comment: There is no accept answer button on my screen lol.... Or I would I am sorry......

Comment: It's not a button. It's an outline of a check mark to the left of the answer, beneath the down arrow that's under the number. If there really isn't a check mark, you should post on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ with a screen shot showing the top part of an answer to one of your questions and the number next to it without a check mark, because that means something is seriously broken. For your own questions, there should be a hollow check mark to the left of each answer, which turns green when you click it.

Answer (score 0):

Not as succinct, but I'm a fan of not over-pipelining in PowerShell.

```
[String]                   $strBaseDir       = "c:\temp";
[String]                   $strFileFilter    = "*.txt";
[Int]                      $intDayThreshold  = 7;
[System.IO.FileSystemInfo] $objFile          = $null;
[Int]                      $intLastWriteDays = 0;
[String]                   $strLogFileName   = "d:\data\yourlogfile.log";

Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $strBaseDir -Filter $strFileFilter -Recurse | Where-Object{ ! $_.PSIsContainer } |
    Foreach-Object {
        $objFile = $_;

        $intLastWriteDays = [Math]::Round((New-TimeSpan -Start $objFile.LastWriteTime -End (Get-Date)).TotalDays);

        if ( $intLastWriteDays -ge $intDayThreshold ) {
            Write-Output -InputObject ( "{0:G} : Deleting file [{1}] with last write time of [{2:G}], which is [{3}] day(s) ago." -f (Get-Date), $objFile.FullName, $objFile.LastWriteTime, $intLastWriteDays ) | Add-Content -Path $strLogFileName -PassThru;
            $objFile | Remove-Item -Force -ErrorAction silentlyContinue;
            if ( ! $? ) {
                Write-Output -InputObject "ERROR : Failed to remove file." | Add-Content -Path $strLogFileName -PassThru;
                } #if
        } else {
            Write-Output -InputObject ( "{0:G} : Skipping file [{1}] with last write time of [{2:G}], which is [{3}] day(s) ago." -f (Get-Date), $objFile.FullName, $objFile.LastWriteTime, $intLastWriteDays ) | Add-Content -Path $strLogFileName -PassThru;
        } #else-if

        } #Foreach-Object
```

Comment: Okay I understand what to change but is it possible for the `[String]                   $strFileFilter    = "*.txt";` to be modified to be any file type? I'm just wondering because I want to use this script to delete any files of any type automatically. So what do I put for the `.txt` part of the script? Also if I run the script I get an error (sorry) I'll post the modified script in a pic and the error in a pic (Plz note where it says `.torrent` I would like that to actually be any file type). ERROR PICTURE: http://bit.ly/15gsKcO MODIFIED SCRIPT PICTURE: http://bit.ly/10z6v9x